# passing values by buttons and count the whole thing

Tags: android, button, android-activity, onclicklistener

I have 3 classes. In every class I have 2 buttons like yes and no.
I want to pass 1 for yes and 0 for no.Finally I want to count the total number,
I mean if someone presses ' yes ' every time then it should be 3. 
How to do it?`

---

### passing values by buttons and count the whole thing

```
    //this is 1st class
    package com.atlantis.learnactivities;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class Main extends Activity {


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
            b1.setOnClickListener (new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    startActivity(new Intent(Main.this,Second.class));
                }
            });

            Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);
            b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    startActivity(new Intent(Main.this,Second.class));
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

    }
```

//this is 2nd class

```
    package com.atlantis.learnactivities;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class Second extends Activity {
        String gender =null;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.second);

            Button b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b3);
            b3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    startActivity(new Intent(Second.this,Three.class));
                }
            });
            Button b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b4);
            b4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    startActivity(new Intent(Second.this,Four.class));
                }
            });



        }
    }
```

Comment: use shared preferences. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Answer (score 0):

Use **sharedPreference**. 
When click `button` add an integer value.

To add

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putInt("btn_value", "value");
editor.commit();
```

To retrieve data from shared preference

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE); 

 int value = prefs.getInt("btn_value", -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your current Activity, create a new Intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Main.this, Second.class);
i.putExtra("new_variable_name","value");
startActivity(i);
```

Then in the Second Activity, retrieve those values:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String value = extras.getString("new_variable_name");
}
```

You don't need to use SharedPreferences to pass data in the same application.

Answer (score 0):

***If you don't need to Store the values and just pass it from one class to the next***, use putExtra with intent.
Eg. Inside your click listener:

```
    intent.putExtra("value", 1);  
//or intent.putExtra("value", "1") , depending on whether you want to use it as a String or int
```

And in the class you are passing the value to, retrieve it

```
this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("value");  
//this.getIntent().getExtras().getInt("value");
```

check:
http://pkhandroid.wordpress.com/2012/10/02/post9-intent-message-passing-within-activities/
http://mobileorchard.com/android-app-development-using-intents-to-pass-data-and-return-results-between-activities/